# Accessing Servers behind double NAT

Tags: nat, linux, network-access, route-server

Basically, 
I want to know every possible way to access Linux servers or any other devices located behind ISP'S (Carrier-grade NAT) and our local NAT.
I have used VPN and forward-reverse tunneling because I have one public server on Google. But I want to know if I am missing out any other way maybe without the need of public gateway server.
I just need to access that server from anywhere.
Thnx!!!

Comment: Your ISP should not be using CGN on your business account. CGN is for residential accounts in order to save public addresses for the business accounts.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your ISP has got special provisions, you can't reverse-NAT/port-forward through CG-NAT.

The only solution besides VPN - essentially reversing the intial connection direction - is a NAT-free IPv6 connection.